# Range of values for individual words which could be given in Vader while customizing

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, vader

What is the range of numbers which could be assigned to a **word** while customizing the Vader sentiment package. In customization, I wanted to add more words and assign them the sentiment score.

Answer (score 0):

The value ranges from -4 to 4. It would be helpful when you would be customizing the package by adding newer words.